# Overriding method is not working in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

I have override the magento sales block method in my custom module and the method defined the function is not working. AFter overriding default.phtml not working

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" type="mymodule\OrderTransactioncode\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" />
</config>
```

> app/code/mymodule/OrderTransactioncode/Block/Order/Item/Renderer

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace mymodule\OrderTransactioncode\Block\Order\Item\Renderer;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditMemo\Item as CreditMemoItem;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item as InvoiceItem;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item as OrderItem;


class DefaultRenderer extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer
{
    /**
     * Magento string lib
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
     */
    protected $string;


    protected $_productOptionFactory;

   protected $lendinginstitutiondoc;


   /* public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        //\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,

        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->_productOptionFactory = $productOptionFactory;        
        parent::__construct($context,$string,$productOptionFactory, $data);
    }*/



    /**
     * Accept option value and return its formatted view
     *
     * @param mixed $optionValue
     * Method works well with these $optionValue format:
     *      1. String
     *      2. Indexed array e.g. array(val1, val2, ...)
     *      3. Associative array, containing additional option info, including option value, e.g.
     *          array
     *          (
     *              [label] => ...,
     *              [value] => ...,
     *              [print_value] => ...,
     *              [option_id] => ...,
     *              [option_type] => ...,
     *              [custom_view] =>...,
     *          )
     *
     * @return array
     * @SuadfasdfppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */


    public function getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue)
    {

        //$optionValue =  array("test","testing");
        $optionInfo = [];
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $doc_collection = $objectManager->create('mymodule\Pathway\Model\Docstatus');


        //print_r($optionValue);
        //exit;

        // define input data format
        if (is_array($optionValue)) {
            if (isset($optionValue['option_id'])) {
                $optionInfo = $optionValue;
                if (isset($optionInfo['value'])) {

                    $optionValue = $optionInfo['value'];
                }
            } elseif (isset($optionValue['value'])) {
                $optionValue = $optionValue['value'];
            }
        }


        // render customized option view
        if (isset($optionInfo['custom_view']) && $optionInfo['custom_view']) {


                // code customized for adding document status 

              $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                      $firstoptionModel = $objectManager->get('\Itoris\DynamicProductOptions\Model\Option')->getCollection()
                      ->addFieldToFilter('orig_option_id',$optionInfo['option_id'])->getData(); 

                      $configuration = $firstoptionModel[0]['configuration'];

                      $decodedjson = json_decode($configuration,true);

                      $optioncssclass= $decodedjson['items']; 

                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                     $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order');

                       $ordercode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');

                       $order_col =  $order->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('transaction_code', ['eq' =>$ordercode]);

                       $orderid = $order_col->getFirstItem()->getId();

                      $sku = array();   

                    $_default = ['value' => $optionValue];

            if (isset($optionInfo['option_type'])) {


                try {

                    $group = $this->_productOptionFactory->create()->groupFactory($optionInfo['option_type']);                                        
                     $seperate = explode("<br/>",$optionInfo['value']);
                     $doc_track_status =  array();
                     $filter_array = array_filter($optioncssclass);                     

                     $i = 0 ;
                     $get_document =  array();
                   foreach($filter_array as $key=> $typ){


                          $sku[] = $typ['sku'];
                          $doc_track_status = $doc_collection->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', ['eq' => $orderid])
                            ->addFieldToFilter('doc_id', ['eq' => $typ['sku']])
                            ->toArray(); 

                            $doc_track_status['items'][0]['name'] = $seperate[$i];

                            foreach($doc_track_status['items']  as $doc_status){


                                if(empty($doc_status['order_status'])){
                                    $doc_order_status = "";
                                }else{
                                    $doc_order_status = $doc_status['order_status'];
                                }

                    $get_document[] = implode(" ",array("name"=>$doc_status['name'],"status"=>"<span style='font-weight:bold'>".$doc_order_status."</span>"));

                            }
                        $i++;                   
                      } 
                      //echo '<pre>';
                      //print_r($get_document); 
                      $string_version = implode('<br/>', $get_document);
                    return ['value' => $string_version];

                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    return $_default;
                }
            }
            return $_default;
        }

        // truncate standard view
        $result = [];




        if (is_array($optionValue)) {
            $truncatedValue = implode("\n", $optionValue);
            $truncatedValue = nl2br($truncatedValue);
            return ['value' => $truncatedValue];
        } else {                            
            $truncatedValue = $this->filterManager->truncate($optionValue, ['length' => 55, 'etc' => '']);            
            $get_temp_id = $this->_lendinginstitutiondoc->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('docname', array('eq' => $optionValue))->getFirstItem()->getTemplateId();                                
            echo $get_temp_id."<span style='font-weight:bold'></span>";                 
            $truncatedValue = nl2br($truncatedValue);
        }



        $result = ['value' => $truncatedValue];

        if ($this->string->strlen($optionValue) > 55) {
            $result['value'] = $result['value'] . ' <a href="#" class="dots tooltip toggle" onclick="return false">...</a>';
            $optionValue = nl2br($optionValue);
            $result = array_merge($result, ['full_view' => $optionValue]);
        }

        return $result;
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: In default.phtml the method is using but the file is not working

Answer (score 0):

**mymodule** is wrong name. Should be Mymodule. I have tried same way, it's working fine for me.

> 1. Make sure sequence tag added your module.xml

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
</sequence>
```

> Your module.xml should be looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mymodule_OrderTransactioncode" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now **app/code/mymodule/OrderTransactioncode/Block/Order/Item/Renderer** Shoule be **app/code/Mymodule/OrderTransactioncode/Block/Order/Item/Renderer**

```
namespace Mymodule\OrderTransactioncode\Block\Sales\Order\Item\Renderer;


class DefaultRenderer extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer
{
    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getItem()
    {error_log('--PPPP--');
        return parent::getItem();
    }

    public function getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue)
    {
        error_log('getFormatedOptionValue');
        return parent::getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue);
    }
}
```

> Change your di.xml too

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" type="Mymodule\OrderTransactioncode\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" />
</config>
```